# progress not being updated while downloading a file

Tags: c++, libcurl, gtk2

I'm trying to create a simple file downloader using GTK2 and curl.

As you can see in below example ,the progress it self is being calculated and updated using a separate thread, but for some reason it doesn't work properly. Even though the progress is not moving I can see that the file is being downloaded.

Could anyone please review the below code and let me know what is wrong there?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

size_t my_write_func(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
{
  return fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
}

size_t my_read_func(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)
{
  return fread(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
}

GtkWidget *Bar;
int my_progress_func(GtkWidget *bar,
                     double t, /* dltotal */
                     double d, /* dlnow */
                     double ultotal,
                     double ulnow)
{
    printf("progress : %f \n", (d*100.0)/t);
    gdk_threads_enter();
    gtk_progress_set_value(GTK_PROGRESS(bar), (d*100.0)/t);
    gdk_threads_leave();
    return 0;
}

void *my_thread(void *ptr)
{
  CURL * curl;
  FILE *outfile;
  gchar *url = (gchar *) ptr;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl)
  {
    CURLcode res;
    outfile = fopen("test.exe", "w");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); /// Follow redirections ////
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, "172.16.3.3:3128");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, outfile);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, my_write_func);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, my_read_func);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, my_progress_func);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA, Bar);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));

    fclose(outfile);
    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }

  return NULL;
}

/// Window events ////
static void destroy_event(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    gtk_main_quit();
}
static gboolean delete_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data)
{
    return FALSE; /// must return false to trigger destroy event for window
}
/// ///////////// ////

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    GtkWidget *Window, *Frame, *Frame2;
    GtkAdjustment *adj;

    /* Must initialize libcurl before any threads are started */
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    /* Init thread */
    g_thread_init(NULL);

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    /// Window ///////
    Window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (Window), "Downloader");
    /// Widnow signals /////
    //g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(Window), "delete_event", G_CALLBACK(delete_event), NULL);
    //g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(Window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(destroy_event), NULL);
    /// Widnow signals /////

    Frame = gtk_frame_new(NULL);
    gtk_frame_set_shadow_type(GTK_FRAME(Frame), GTK_SHADOW_OUT);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(Window), Frame);

    Frame2 = gtk_frame_new(NULL);
    gtk_frame_set_shadow_type(GTK_FRAME(Frame2), GTK_SHADOW_IN);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(Frame), Frame2);
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(Frame2), 5);

    adj = (GtkAdjustment*)gtk_adjustment_new(0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0);
    Bar = gtk_progress_bar_new_with_adjustment(adj);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(Frame2), Bar);

    gtk_widget_show_all(Window);

    if (!g_thread_create(&my_thread, argv[1], FALSE, NULL) != 0){
        g_warning("can't create the thread");
    }

    gdk_threads_enter();
    gtk_main();
    gdk_threads_leave();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should I add this to my thread to allow GTK to refresh the UI? 
`while (gtk_events_pending ()){
        gtk_main_iteration ();
    }`  But even with this in the thread , it's not working properly..

Answer (score 0):

GTK widgets have to be updated from the main thread.

I implemented a progress bar some time back, but with the help of timer.

Install a timer before calling gtk_main() and update the widget in timer callback.

It can be done with threads also, but a producer-consumer model needs to be followed  and it's more complex.

Here is a nice link:
[http://www.cc.gatech.edu/data_files/public/doc/gtk/tutorial/gtk_tut-10.html][1]